# How do I put my Django SQLite database contents into a Heroku PostGreSQL database?

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am totally new to hosting/deploying applications. After watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DI_7Zja8Zc), he started a new database from scratch rather than converting his Django SQLite database. I have lots of data that I want on the deployed site so I'd like some advice as to how to do that with Django and Heroku. I have seen there are some SQLite -> PostGreSQL conversion questions on here but none seemed to show a step by step guide using Django and Heroku, only issues they're having. I just want to make sure I do it right.

Comment: Here are some tips: Use the same database server in development as you are in production. Don't consider data in your database part of your application—data generally _shouldn't_ be the same in multiple environments. If you need to add production data, do it in your production database. You can try using [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) and [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#loaddata), but you might run into issues. Also, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/

Comment: But really this question isn't about converting from sqlite to Postgres, but about copying your data from development to production.

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution could be using [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) and [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) management commands from Django.

For example, locally you would do:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata > somefile
```

then on your deployment you could do:

```
$ python manage.py loaddata somefile
```

This is not the ideal solution, but for simple use cases could definitely do the trick.

**Note:** you would have to first upload the `somefile` to your server, in this case heroku.